# timezone id to short timezone (pst, pdt, cst, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, google-maps-api-3, timezone

I use Googles Timezone API to get TimeZoneID and I pass it to the ruby gem TZInfo to get the local time. How can I get the Timezones short name (PST, PDT, EST, etc...) from this info. I tried `strftime(%Z)` but that returns 'UTC'. This is a ruby on rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TZInfo::Timezone#strftime`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Timezone#strftime-instance_method) ought to work:

```
require "tzinfo"

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get("America/New_York")
puts tz.strftime("%Z")
```

If you tried that and it didn't work, that's mysterious.

Alternatively, you can use [`TZInfo::TimezonePeriod#abbreviation`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/TimezonePeriod#abbreviation-instance_method):

```
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
period = tz.period_for_utc(Time.now.utc)
puts period.abbreviation
```

Comment: I was trying 'tz.now.strftime("%Z")' which was returning 'UTC'. you solution of 'tz.strftime("%Z")' worked!